# Random Walk in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random, stochastic-process

I am trying to create a simple random walk. This is the code that I wrote.

```
 n=50;
 p=0.5;

Y=zeros(n,1);
X=zeros(n,1);
X(1)=0;

for i=1:length(n)
    Y(i,1)=(rand(1)<=p);
end

for i=1:length(n)
    X(i+1)=X(i)+(2*Y(i)-1);
end
plot(1:n,X,'.-')
```

However, in this if I check `Y`, which stores the random Bernoulli variables,I get all zeroes. Why does it happen?

I get a plot like, [image: this].
Which doesn't look like a random walk. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong

Comment: `length(n)` is 1, since it's a number. You want `for i=1:n`

Comment: @NoelSeguraMeraz Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding Noel's comment, indeed the `length(n)` should be replaced by `n` and the plot function should be `plot(1:(n+1),X,'.-')` instead as there are `n+1` elements in X. You end up with the following:

```
n=50;
p=0.5;

Y=zeros(n,1);
X=zeros(n,1);
X(1)=0;

for i=1:n
    Y(i,1)=(rand(1)<=p);
end

for i=1:n
    X(i+1)=X(i)+(2*Y(i)-1);
end
plot(1:(n+1),X,'.-')
```

The plot looks more like a random walk:

[image]